# Batch/CMD Error "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory-structure

I'm trying to write a batch/cmd file that will rename directories when it finds " - " that is SpaceDashSpace. I thought I had everything I needed by outputting things via Echo and not actually renaming them. Next I tested it on a few directories and it worked perfectly.

When I tried to move it to a networked folder/sub folder I found I needed the PushD command. Again all is well if I run it in a specific directory.

Path information would look something like:

```
\\MyNetworkStorage\TopLevelFolder\Music
```

Followed by:

```
Artist1
    Artist1 - Album1
    Artist1 - Album2
    Artist1 - Album3
Artist2
    Artist2 - Album1
    Artist2 - Album2
```

You get the idea.

If I kick the batch file off in either:

- \MyNetworkStorate\TopLevelFolder\Music\Artist1 or
- \MyNetworkStorate\TopLevelFolder\MusicArtist2

all is good. If I try to do it from one level up, that is:

- \MyNetworkStorate\TopLevelFolder\Music

I get the following error for every single directory.:

"The system cannot find the file specified"

Googling tells me the path might be to long and I've followed instructions to

- Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative
  Templates > System > Filesystem
- Double click the Enable Win32 Long
  paths option and enable it

Another suggestion was when running my .cmd file on the local machine to preface it with:
**cmd.exe /c** MyCmdFile.cmd

Nothing I've searched for has fixed my problem.

I'm new to batch files so perhaps the problem is actually in what I've cobbled together the last 1.5 days. At this point I wish I wrote a C# program for it. I thought this would be simple. Any suggestings?

Again if I start it in any specific Artist's directory it will rename all the sub-directories removing the "Artists Name - " portion and leave just the album name as I want it to. When I move up to the directory that contains all the artists, it fails. I'm changing this on line that starts with "PUSHD" of the command file.

```
@Echo Off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

PUSHD \\MyNetwork\Music\HighRez <<<---This fails
PUSHD \\MyNetwork\Music\HighRez\Any Artist I pick <<<---This works for all sub directories
:: If this fails then exit
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto:eof
:: other commands...

FOR /D /r %%G in ("* - *") DO (
SET DirName=%%~nxG

set "NewName=!DirName:* - =!"

Echo Renaming from "!DirName!" To "!NewName!"

REM ***Remove REM from line below to actually rename once you are happy with results
ren "!DirName!" "!NewName!"
)
popd
```

Comment: The default path limit is already pretty long; I doubt you're hitting it based on your description. It sounds like you've got a permissions issue with the HighRez folder and you aren't allowed to enter it, but subfolder permissions are configured correctly.

Comment: I agree the path length thing seemed unlikely, given some artist/album names are quite long. And since it works when I try long ones by the specific artist it works fine. Pluss it fails for all, never a single one when I start at that higher level.

Comment: You should be using `%%G` instead of `!DirName!` for the rename command.

Comment: @Squashman I get the same error. However I now see what I think is the mapped drive and partial path that PUSHD adds. 

Original with !DirName!
`Renaming from "Nirvana - Unplugged (24-48)" To "Unplugged (24-48)"
The system cannot find the file specified.`

Renaming from Z:\HighRez\Nirvana\Nirvana - Unplugged (24-48) To "Unplugged (24-48)"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

With %%G:
`Renaming from Z:\HighRez\Nirvana\Nirvana - Unplugged (24-48) To "Unplugged (24-48)"`
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the poor editing on comment above. Actually I see trying to edit that the one starting with Z:\ actually gives a different error message `The syntax of the command is incorrect`

Comment: Your code in your question shows quotes in the rename command but your output example in your comment does not show quotes.  Regardless of needing quotes or not you should always use them as best practice. You have to use `%%G` because that is the full path to the directory name.  The variable `DirName` is just the directory name only and that does not exist in the current working directory.   So the rename command has to be `ren "%%G" "!NewName!"` I would think with whatever programming language you are using, you should always be aware of what the current working directory is.

Comment: Quotes on the ren line around %%G was the final piece of the puzzle. **Thanks** so much. `"!DirName!" "!NewName!"` gave file not found error for reasons @Squashman pointed out, next up was `%%G "!NewName!"` and that gave syntax error. Quotes around both %%G and !NewName! did it as in `"%%G" "!NewName!"` I'm a bit confused as I thought I learned yesterday to put quotes around all my variables...and thought I was. I would not have thought to put them around %%G. As I thought the system would know what that is. Still a bit more learning and figuring out to do.

Comment: Were  you saying above @Squashman that this line `SET DirName=%%~nxG` Should have been `SET "DirName"="%%~nxG"`. Meaning always put quotes around everything?

Comment: The value of the `FOR` variable `%%G` has spaces in it.  Spaces are a command separator.  As I said earlier, ALWAYS use quotes as a best practice.  This `SET "DirName"="%%~nxG"` is not correct syntax.  As I have stated in your previous question you use quotes in the assignment of the variable to protect special characters and spaces. This is correct: `SET "DirName=%%~nxG"`  This does not assign quotes to the variable.  It just protects the assignment of the value to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for anyone who might need something similar. It was the combination of using %%G along with quotes around it as in:

```
ren "%%G" "!NewName!"
```

In place of the original variable "!DirName!"

Working example, finally ;-)

```
@Echo Off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

PUSHD \\NASBoxOnNetwork\Music\HighRez
:: If this fails then exit
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto:eof
:: other commands...

FOR /D /r %%G in ("* - *") DO (
SET DirName=%%~nxG

set "NewName=!DirName:* - =!"

Echo Renaming from "%%G" To !NewName!

REM ***Remove REM from line below to actually rename once you are happy with results
ren "%%G" "!NewName!"
)
popd
```